# Parallel Foreach counting

Tags: c#, parallel-processing

My question is a lot similar to [Parallel Foreach Race Condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15840186/parallel-foreach-race-condition)

But it wasn't answered very clear and it differs in the sense that I need to count which object in the for-each meets a certain criteria. If it does it needs to add it to the list.

so something like this

```
List<int> MetCriteria = new List<int>();
Parallel.ForEach(dt.AsEnumerable(), (entry,state) => {

  if (Convert.ToInt32(entry["Time"]) > 100)//in miliseconds
     MetCriteria.add(Convert.ToInt32(entry["EntryID"]);
});
```

So obviously this list does not contain all the values that a normal for each would because I require some way to keep the `MetCriteria` object in sync, like a thread lock or something but i am unsure of how to do this

any help please

Comment: Is the `if` statement literally what you're trying to do? If so why are you using parallel processing?

Comment: I have to do different things based on the amount, so if it is above 100 it met-criteria if it hasn't then other variables need to be checked and also added in a separate list. then I have to call a web-service on each of the entries that may take some time based on the entry time

Comment: Are you simply comparing values like `Convert.ToInt32(entry["Time"]) > 100` and adding the items to a list and afterwards then calling a web service? Or are you calling a web service inside the `if`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use thread safe collection like [ConcurrentBag](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381779(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
var MetCriteria = new ConcurrentBag<int>();
Parallel.ForEach(dt.AsEnumerable(), (entry,state) => {

  if (Convert.ToInt32(entry["Time"]) > 100)//in miliseconds
     MetCriteria.add(Convert.ToInt32(entry["EntryID"]);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can lock your list to make it threat safe. But I would use a thread safe collection like Dovydas Sopa suggested.

```
List<int> MetCriteria = new List<int>();
Parallel.ForEach(dt.AsEnumerable(), (entry, state) =>
{
    if (Convert.ToInt32(entry["Time"]) > 100)//in miliseconds
    {
        lock (MetCriteria)
        {
            MetCriteria.Add(Convert.ToInt32(entry["EntryID"]));
        }

    }
});
```

Comment: Which one would be more resource friendly. this answer or Dovydas Sopa's

Comment: if i were to use your answer and I had an if statement out side that lock, like `if (MetCriteria.count > 1000)` it should not effect it right(its just reading data, not changing)?

Comment: Accept Dovydas Sopa's answer, this is the way how it should be done. Lock just prevents simultanious acces from different threads and makes it _thread safe_. Technically the object is locked and another accessing thread has to wait until the previous action is finished

Comment: I understand thank you for the explanation fubo upvoted :)